# Using for each to toggle checkboxes stopped working

Tags: javascript

The code(for selecting multiple check boxes) below worked fine last night(in every browser), but today it gives errors(in every browser) like:

1. toggle not defined.
2. expected (  line:4 after for.

This keeps happening all the time...
CODE:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo[]');
    for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
    checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar1"> Bar 1<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar2"> Bar 2<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar3"> Bar 3<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar4"> Bar 4<br/>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: For each or foreach ... Remove the `each` since it is deprecated

Comment: try wrapping your function toggle code in "window.onload = (function(){  //your code here  });

Comment: No, this code never worked. Maybe you had cached version of something else.

Comment: @TommyBs - that would just move it out of scope, and the window doesn't have to be loaded to create a function, but the function is full of errors?

Comment: If you can't see it for yourself: first, the "each" cause syntax error.  Second, "checkbox" in every iteration is a number, the index of the checkbox in the array. As such, trying to set its "checked" property is meaningless.

Comment: @adeneo good point, I was thinking he was calling the function on load for some reason and just assumed document.getElementsByName was failing due to the Dom not being ready.//note to self read question more carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be a [for each in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) in JS 1.6 and there is recently an [array.foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

But I suggest you use a for loop like this since you have a collection

```
function toggle(source) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo[]');
  for (var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `checkboxes[i].checked`? :)

Comment: thanks it worked.....but I'm sure the code worked for me for the first time...
I m new to javascript... Any tips for learning it on www

Comment: It is possible that the code worked in Firefox and chrome due to the for each being available there. for tutorials, google javascript tutorials